# How to create a circular navigation menu using Cocoa and swift for mac desktop applications?

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, user-interface, cocoa

I'm trying to create a circular navigation menu using cocoa for a mac desktop applications that looks like this

[image: Circular menu]

But i'm not sure how to go about it any help would be great thanks

Comment: can i not get them for the mac desktop applications? also I want to create a circular menu similar to but not the exact picture I posted

Comment: Check if this helps https://github.com/Ramotion/circle-menu

Comment: I'll check it out thank you.